# Can't replicate this graph using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm having trouble replicating this graph

[image: graph]

I know it's silly to do a graph with so little info, but my teacher demands it.. go figure...

I can't seem to make the bars stick together.
It's my first attempt at TikZ ever...

what I've done so far:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{pfgplots}
\begin{document}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
     \begin{axis}[ symbolic x coords={18S, HNF1, Normalização dos valores para 18S}, xtick=data]  
    \addplot[ybar,fill=black] coordinates { 
      (18S,42) 
      (HNF1,50) 
      (Normalização dos valores para 18S,80) 
 }; 
    \addplot[ybar,fill=gray] coordinates { 
      (18S,50) 
      (HNF1,30) 
      (Normalização dos valores para 18S, 100) 
 };  
  \end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please post what you have so far. That way we don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={18S, HNF1, Normalização dos valores para 18S}, 
    xtick=data]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=black] coordinates {
        (18S,42)
        (HNF1,50)
        (Normalização dos valores para 18S,80)
    };
    \addplot[ybar,fill=gray] coordinates {
        (18S,50)
        (HNF1,30)
        (Normalização dos valores para 18S, 100)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}` this is more or less the example in the manual, I've been wrapping my head around the manual for some time now, guess this will take some time and patience

Comment: Santiago, you should make this into a complete small document (with a `\documentclass{article}` and `begin{document}` etc.) and edit your question to include it, instead of adding the code as a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the code you posted:

- By specifying `ybar` in each `\addplot` command, you cause the bars to be put on top of each other. Specify the `ybar` once in the `\axis` command.
- the `ybar` (or `xbar`) allows a value which determines the separation between bars at the same x (or y) tick.  Set this to 0 to get the bars adjacent.
- Symbolic axes don't like accented characters as far as I can tell.  So the way around this problem (which also makes entering the data easier), is to use an arbitrary symbolic label like `{A,B,C}` and then use `xticklabels` to supply the labels.  This also allows you to put the long label into a `tabular` environment, so it will wrap correctly.)
- To get the long label to fit you need to enlarge the limits.

Here's a new version of your plot: (by the way, your numbers don't match your picture!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}     
  \begin{axis}[ybar=0pt,
    symbolic x coords={A, B, C}, 
    xtick={A, B, C}, 
    xticklabels={18S, HNF1,
       \begin{tabular}{c}Normalização\\dos valores\\para 18S\end{tabular}},
    enlargelimits=0.3,bar width=20pt]  
    \addplot[fill=black] coordinates { 
      (A,42) 
      (B,50) 
      (C,80) 
 }; 
    \addplot[fill=gray] coordinates { 
      (A,50) 
      (B,30) 
      (C, 100) 
 };  
  \end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture} 



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! you saved my essay with that 0 hehe. I think I can do the rest.. thanks again :D

Comment: @Santiago I hope your essay wasn't "reproduce this graph using tikZ" :-) Since the answer solved your problem you should click on the checkmark icon to accept the answer.

Comment: I wish... and sorry, I'm new here and am still getting familiar with the interface. thanks again ;)

Comment: @Santiago No need to apologize, and welcome. It's sometimes good to wait for a few answers before accepting an answer anyway, since there may be multiple good answers to certain questions. But in this case I think your problem was solved quite directly. Accepting answers is very helpful to others who might have a similar question since they can quickly see  that the answer worked.